# Cannot manipulate lists

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am new to python and trying to integrate a sample from my problem domain in python and getting the following error:

```
sum_square_error += (output[0:1] - expected) ** 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

The program:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
import numpy as np
import sys as sys

from neat import nn, population, statistics

# Network inputs and expected outputs.
#xor_inputs = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
#xor_outputs = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]

xor_inputs = [[-14.7569, 17.9667, -55.0074, -0.218445, 0.835469, 11.23]]

''',
              [-23.8745,7.40331,-48.5434,0.114681,-0.0208769,15.2138],
              [-22.2368,7.02313,-54.734,0.0633238,-0.097209,12.7707],
              [-19.0957,7.03371,-48.6117,0.108994,-0.0357287,15.205]]
'''

xor_outputs = [[-31.1812, 47.2076, -34.9315, 62.6799]]
''',
               [-53.9514,97.2412,55.7927,92.506],
               [-27.417,47.7492,-28.1557,78.6016],
               [-57.4506,99.2558,55.7436,92.3611]]
'''


def eval_fitness(genomes):
    for g in genomes:
        net = nn.create_feed_forward_phenotype(g)

        sum_square_error = 0.0
        for inputs, expected in zip(xor_inputs, xor_outputs):
            # Serial activation propagates the inputs through the entire network.
            output = net.serial_activate(inputs)
#            print(xor_inputs[0:1])
#            print(xor_outputs[0:1])
#            sys.exit(0)
            sum_square_error += (output[0] - expected) ** 2

        # When the output matches expected for all inputs, fitness will reach
        # its maximum value of 1.0.
        g.fitness = 1 - sum_square_error


local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'xor2_config')
pop = population.Population(config_path)
pop.run(eval_fitness, 300)

# Log statistics.
statistics.save_stats(pop.statistics)
statistics.save_species_count(pop.statistics)
statistics.save_species_fitness(pop.statistics)

print('Number of evaluations: {0}'.format(pop.total_evaluations))

# Show output of the most fit genome against training data.
winner = pop.statistics.best_genome()
print('\nBest genome:\n{!s}'.format(winner))
print('\nOutput:')
winner_net = nn.create_feed_forward_phenotype(winner)
for inputs, expected in zip(xor_inputs, xor_outputs):
    output = winner_net.serial_activate(inputs)
    print("expected {0:1.5f} got {1:1.5f}".format(expected, output[0]))
```

I have searched the error and found that it needs to be converted into numpy array. When i convert the xor_inputs and xor_outputs to numpy arrays then it says:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It should be noted that the initial problem of xor has 2 inputs in 2d array and 1 output in the 1d output array. In my problem i have 6 inputs in 2d array and 4 outputs in 2d output array.

Comment: At which code did this error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous...` happen?

Comment: Replacing `output[0:1]` by `output[0]` will fix the first error you mentioned. The latter is the element you want, the former is the 1-item list which contains that element.

Answer (score 1):

Although I didn't read your program carefully, a way to implement the sum of square error with list is:

```
>>> va=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
>>> vb=[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
>>> sum((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(va,vb))
4.0
```

To understand this, try:

```
>>> [(a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(va,vb)]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

You can do this with NumPy more easily:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> va=np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
>>> vb=np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> sum((va-vb)*(va-vb))
4.0
```

OR

```
>>> import numpy.linalg as la
>>> la.norm(va-vb)**2
4.0
```

`(va-vb)*(va-vb)` gives an inner product of `(va-vb)` and `(va-vb)`, so its sum gives a squared norm of `(va-vb)`.  `la.norm` gives a norm of a given vector.

I think above will be helpful (and a solution) to your problem.

Regarding the question:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This happens when you are expecting to get a boolean value from a boolean list.  Let's see an example:

```
>>> va=np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
>>> vb=np.array([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> va==vb
array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

>>> 1 if va==vb else 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Now it's clear that Python does not understand if we expect AND of (va==vb) or OR of it.  `(va==vb).any()` gives OR (true if at least one of elements is true), and `(va==vb).all()` gives AND (true if all elements are true).

```
>>> (va==vb).any()
True
>>> (va==vb).all()
False
>>> 1 if (va==vb).all() else 0
0
```